# Facebook share dialog opens blank popup - but works on reload?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I had a working share dialog until 2 days ago and now all of a sudden it doesn't work anymore. No changes were made on my side, not in the code, and not in the developer center.

Suddenly, clicking the share button opens a blank popup instead of the share dialog, even though the URL of the popup is correct. And when I reload the popup, it shows the dialog correctly!

For simplicity, I have created a test page within my app containing only the share button. Here is the code of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="453494284796333" /> 
        <meta property="og:type" content="fircikonline:share" /> 
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://light-speed-games.com/apps/sharebuttons/sharebutton.php?id=58667&desc=Igraj%20i%20ti%20Fircik%20besplatno%20onlajn,%20zabavi%20se%20i%20takmi%C4%8Di%20sa%20prijateljima.&img=https://light-speed-games.com/apps/fircik/images/logo125.png&title=Pobedio%20sam%20u%20Firciku!&url=https://apps.facebook.com/fircikonline/&aid=453494284796333?id=4&desc=Igraj i ti Fircik besplatno onlajn, zabavi se i takmiči sa prijateljima.&img=https://light-speed-games.com/apps/fircik/images/logo125.png&title=Pobedio sam u Firciku!" /> 
        <meta property="og:title" content="Pobedio sam u Firciku!" /> 
        <meta property="og:image" content="https://light-speed-games.com/apps/fircik/images/logo125.png" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="Igraj i ti Fircik besplatno onlajn, zabavi se i takmiči sa prijateljima." />
    </head>
    <body style='padding:0;margin:0;'>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
            FB.init({
                  appId      : '453494284796333',
                  xfbml      : true,
                  version    : 'v2.2'
                });

                function share() {
                FB.ui({
                   method: 'share_open_graph',
                   action_type: 'fircikonline:share',
                   action_properties: JSON.stringify({
                     type: 'fircikonline:share',
                     object: 'http://light-speed-games.com/apps/sharebuttons/sharebutton.php?id=58667&desc=Igraj%20i%20ti%20Fircik%20besplatno%20onlajn,%20zabavi%20se%20i%20takmi%C4%8Di%20sa%20prijateljima.&img=https://light-speed-games.com/apps/fircik/images/logo125.png&title=Pobedio%20sam%20u%20Firciku!&url=https://google.com&aid=453494284796333?id=4&desc=Igraj i ti Fircik besplatno onlajn, zabavi se i takmiči sa prijateljima.&img=https://light-speed-games.com/apps/fircik/images/logo125.png&title=Pobedio sam u Firciku!',
                     href: 'https://google.com'
                   })
                 });
            }
        </script>
        <a href="#" onclick="share();">Share now</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the URL of the popup: [click here](https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/share_open_graph?action_properties=%7B%22type%22%3A%22fircikonline%3Ashare%22%2C%22object%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Flight-speed-games.com%2Fapps%2Fsharebuttons%2Fsharebutton.php%3Fid%3D58667%26desc%3DIgraj%2520i%2520ti%2520Fircik%2520besplatno%2520onlajn%2C%2520zabavi%2520se%2520i%2520takmi%25C4%258Di%2520sa%2520prijateljima.%26img%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Flight-speed-games.com%2Fapps%2Ffircik%2Fimages%2Flogo125.png%26title%3DPobedio%2520sam%2520u%2520Firciku!%26url%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Ffircikonline%2F%26aid%3D453494284796333%3Fid%3D10343%26desc%3DIgraj%20i%20ti%20Fircik%20besplatno%20onlajn%2C%20zabavi%20se%20i%20takmi%C4%8Di%20sa%20prijateljima.%26img%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Flight-speed-games.com%2Fapps%2Ffircik%2Fimages%2Flogo125.png%26title%3DPobedio%20sam%20u%20Firciku!%22%2C%22href%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%22%7D&action_type=fircikonline%3Ashare&app_id=453494284796333&display=popup&e2e=%7B%7D&locale=en_US&next=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2F7r8gQb8MIqE.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df3150349d1b4376%26domain%3Dlight-speed-games.com%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Flight-speed-games.com%252Ff15cd671728aa5%26relation%3Dopener%26frame%3Df35b8e173d15cca%26result%3D%2522xxRESULTTOKENxx%2522&sdk=joey&version=v2.2)

This is the actual share button with the real URL, app ID and everything. The share button will not work for you because you are not a user of the app, but if you give me your FB ID I will add you as a test user and you can test it yourself.

I'm not getting my hopes up, but does anyone have any idea whatsoever what Facebook is up to now and how I can work around it?

Ideally I would like to get this to work properly, but if not possible for whatever insane reason there may be, then are any of the following hacks possible:

1) load the share dialog once in an invisible iframe, then load it again in the popup hoping the second one will work?

2) make the API return the URL so I can load it in an invisible iframe directly before showing the popup, again hoping the second one will work?

3) reload the blank popup?

4) fire off the API twice but somehow force it to open in the same popup instead of loading a new one the second time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your URL working [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Flight-speed-games.com%2Fapps%2Fsharebuttons%2Fsharebutton.php%3Fid%3D58667%26desc%3DIgraj%2520i%2520ti%2520Fircik%2520besplatno%2520onlajn%2C%2520zabavi%2520se%2520i%2520takmi%25C4%258Di%2520sa%2520prijateljima.%26img%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Flight-speed-games.com%2Fapps%2Ffircik%2Fimages%2Flogo125.png%26title%3DPobedio%2520sam%2520u%2520Firciku%21%26url%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Ffircikonline%2F%26aid%3D453494284796333%3Fid%3D4%26desc%3DIgraj+i+ti+Fircik+besplatno+onlajn%2C+zabavi+se+i+takmi%C4%8Di+sa+prijateljima.%26img%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Flight-speed-games.com%2Fapps%2Ffircik%2Fimages%2Flogo125.png%26title%3DPobedio+sam+u+Firciku%21) and you’ll be back to good.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why the "too many redirects" error happens? Under "redirects we had to follow" it seems to redirect to the same page over and over again using the `og:url` tag...but why?

Comment: That is a new question to ask -- please mark this as answered.

Comment: I've figured it out now. The GET parameters were being appended over again after the redirect to the `og:url` parameter, causing the URL to be different each time, which in turn caused a redirect loop.